# What does equally oriented mean

Tags: geometry

> What does it mean for two triangles to be equally oriented?

I have heard this term a lot but I haven't seen a definition of it. I know that in $3$-space two triangles are considered to be equally oriented if we can slide one on top of the other with the vertices aligning if they are similar or congruent. In $2$-space, though, it is more confusing to me. Below is a picture of equally oriented similar triangles $AMN$, $NBM$ and $MNC$ constructed on segment $MN$. I don't get why they are equally oriented though.

Also, does equally oriented only make sense if the triangles are similar or congruent?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Equally oriented means that if you traverse the vertices in the named order, you either go counter-clockwise in both cases, or clockwise in both cases. So $AMN$ and $NBM$ in your figure are both counter-clockwise, so they are equally oriented. $BNM$ and $CMN$ would not be equally oriented. $CNM$ and $MAN$ would both be oriented clockwise, so they would be equally oriented again.

This concept of orientation doesn't translate well to triangles in space, since what appears counter-clockwise from one point will become clockwise from the opposite direction. You have orientation with respect to a given point, but not without that.

Comment: I think the concept of saying equally oriented is outdated. Most people make that implicit when refering to geometrical congruence or similarity.

Comment: Also when referring to two things being equally oriented in $3$D, we can us an alternative definition.

Comment: @Puzzled417 Equal orientation is independent from congruence. You can have shapes which are congruent but orientation-reversed since reflection is an isometry. You can have shapes which have equal orientation but are not even similar, either because you define the order of vertices explicitely or because there is an obvious way how you want to match them. Implicitely restricting congruence to orientation-preserving congruence may make sense in certain contexts, but unless that context is very clear, I'd rather make this explicit. I'm not sure what you meant about an alternative 3D definition.